# how to send sms from my sms app to app

Tags: android, sms

i have used broadcast receiver and captured the sms ..i want to send the sms only from my app to another mobile where my app is installed..i used priority but it didn't work..i want that the mobile sms defualt inbox will not get the sms ..only my app inbox will get the sms..i have made my own database for sms inbox...what to do??

```
//my sms receiver class
package com.example.crypton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
   String str = "";    
   String str2 = ""; 
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                

            str2 +=  msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
           // str2 += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            db.addSMS(new IncomingSMS(str,str2));      
        }


        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(str2));
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
        try {
            c.moveToFirst();
         String  displayName = c.getString(0);
         str2 = displayName;   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            c.close();
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    /* Intent i = new Intent(context, StoreMsg.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("sms", str);
        i.putExtra("phonenumber",str2);
        context.startActivity(i);*/


    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To Stop the Broad Cast Use

```
this.abortBroadcast();
```

Just after finally block

Comment: will the message will not go further to my android default inbox??